# Borrar selección en Input con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como podría borrar u eliminar la selección de un texto contenido en un `<input type="text">` al dar click en un `<button type="button">` con JavaScript / jQuery

Comment: que has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

La solución de [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_clear_input.asp) es otra opción mas corta.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''">Clear input field</button>

<input type="text" value="Blabla" id="myInput">
```

Generalmente con Jquery es algo como:

```
<button id="button1">Click</button>
<input  id="input1" type="text">
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $('#input1').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no malinterprete la pregunta, y te referís a eliminar el texto que tenes seleccionado al presionar un botón, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```js
function funcion()
{
  var ele  = document.getElementById('test');
    var text = ele.value;
    
    text = text.slice(0, ele.selectionStart) + text.slice(ele.selectionEnd);
    ele.value = text;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test">
<button type="button" onclick="funcion()">
Eliminar
</button>
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad!